# NativeScript CleartextHTTPTrafficNotPermitted

Tags: android, angular, http, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I want to make a HTTP-Request to my local Node-Backend. So I configured my AndroidManifest.xml and my network_security_config.xml to allow cleartext HTTP traffic. But it seems that my NativeScript App is not correctly initializing the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="__PACKAGE__"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="__APILEVEL__"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kimera"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|locale|uiMode"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchScreenTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="SET_THEME_ON_LAUNCH" android:resource="@style/AppTheme" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.tns.ErrorReportActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

network_security_config.xml:

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.178.52</domain>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/selfsigned"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </domain-config>
    <debug-overrides>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/selfsigned"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </debug-overrides>
</network-security-config>
```

Where the problem appears:

```
private readonly URL = 'http://192.168.178.52:3000/';

  constructor(private _client: HttpClient) { }

  _getStrips(): Observable<any> {
    return this._client.get(this.URL + 'leds');
  }
```

I am using the `tns preview` function to run the app locally on my real device.
I've been searching for days, but it seems that `cleartextTrafficPermitted` should do the job.
I have no clue, I even tried to fix it by using self-signed SSL-Certificates, but that also didn't worked, so thanks for helping.

Comment: I guess it's because of the IP, the XML config expects a domain name. You don't have to define `android:networkSecurityConfig`, without that it will simply allow http connection anywhere - at least you may try that for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I have tried using the AppManifest.xml in `tns preview` . But these kind of resources aren't shipped to the preview. That's why my configuration didn't work.